# Pass an string array to CreateProcess in for loop for multiple processes

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have to admit that most of the win32 api stuff I am not familiar with in this code. That being said, I would like to incorporate what I do know into my learning process. I am trying to create a for loop that will `CreateProcess` multiple times with different arguments each time. In Visual Studio I get a compile error:

```
source.cpp(138): error C3867: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::c_str': function call        missing argument list; use '&std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::c_str' to create a     pointer to member
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
```

When running the following code:

```
std::string arrString[3] = {"dir","cd ..","dir"};
            int i;
            LPWSTR cmd =L"cmd";

            for(i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
            STARTUPINFO info={sizeof(info)};
            PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
            if (CreateProcess(cmd, arrString[i].c_str, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
            {
                ::WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
                CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
                CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
            }
```

Am I even headed in the right direction?

**EDIT:**

```
            std::string arrString[3] = {"cmd","cmd","cmd"};
            int i;
            LPWSTR cmd =L"cmd";

            for(i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                STARTUPINFO info={sizeof(info)};
                PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
                vector<wchar_t> cmdline(arrString[i].begin(), arrString[i].end()); 
                CreateProcessW(cmd, &cmdline[0], NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo);
                    ::WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
                    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
                    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);

            }
```

Comment: It looks like your intention is to fetch the directory listings of the current directory and the parent directory, but that's not what this code will do. It will start a new process with its own notion of "current directory," and run `dir`. Then it will start *another* process, again with its own separate notion of "current directory," and switch to another directory. Then it will start a *third* process, again inheriting the same current directory as your program, and run `dir` again. You'll get the same directory listing twice. To get a list of files, consider starting with `FindFirstFile`.

Comment: @RobKennedy: You are correct, but I only used those as an example. In my code it is different and the processes can be ran separately. I used these as a way to shorten it for example purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line

```
if (CreateProcess(cmd, arrString[i].c_str, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
```

you wrote `arrString[i].c_str` when you meant `arrString[i].c_str()`.

Comment: now I get an error than const* char is incompatible with parameter type "LPWSTR".

Comment: how can I convert arrString into LPWSTR?

Comment: @arynhard: You are building with _WinAPI_ set to _Unicode_, so it expects a `wchar_t` instead of a `char`. Either use a `std::wstring` or set _WinAPI_ to _MultiByte Character_ at the project settings.

Comment: Thank you but I get a similar error in this case "const wchar_t is incompatible with parameter type LPWSTR"

Comment: If you use `wstring`, you won't be able to call `c_str`; it returns a const pointer, but `CreateProcessW` requires a non-const buffer. Copy the characters into an array or vector and pass that instead.

Comment: @RobKennedy: When you say "Copy the characters into an array or vector and pass that instead" I get a little confused. isn't that what my arrString is?

Comment: ArrString is an array, but it doesn't hold the characters that CreateProcess wants. Those are in the *string* that your array holds. An array of strings is not the same as an array of characters. The c_str function returns a pointer to the buffer in the string, but you're not allowed to modify that buffer, so you need to copy the *characters* somewhere else that *does* allow modification. For example: `vector<wchar_t> cmdline(arrString[i].c_str(), arrString[i].size() + 1); CreateProcessW(cmd, &cmdline[0], ...)`

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: Incidentally, why/how does `CreateProcess` modify its _command line_ argument?

Comment: @RobKennedy: Pluging your code in I get " error C2664: 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector(unsigned int,const wchar_t &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'unsigned int'"

Comment: @arynhard: Seems the parameters are flipped.. You could also use the constructor taking iterators and call it with `arrString[i].begin(), arrString[i].end()`.

Comment: @K-ballo: Your suggestion does compile, thank you! But now I get no action after. Using "cmd" as all three strings in arrString I should fire up three cmd lines consecutively correct?

Comment: @K-ballo, you need to add an extra `'\0'` to the end that way; otherwise, it's not necessarily null-terminated. That's what the `+1` in my comment was for, although I got the parameter order backward.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Even switching the parameters something still does not work. I get the error "error C2664: 'std::vector<_Ty>::vector(unsigned int,const wchar_t &)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char *' to 'const wchar_t &'"

Comment: @K-ballo: My mistake. I need to set cdm = "start cmd". Thanks for your help!

Comment: Another mistake on my part. The above was incorrect. I still get no cmd prompts opening. Another piece of my code I was experimenting with was doing it. Any suggestions to my edit?